# Alternative to cin/cout in qt

Tags: c++, qt

So I'm transitioning a console app I made to a gui app through qt. I have figured out signals/slots as well as everything I need in order to convert it, with the exception of output. In particular outputting a combination of text as well as user inputted variables. So in my console application, I might have something such as:

```
int main()
{
int x, y;
std::cin >> x >> y;
int z = x+y;
std::cout << "those numbers add to " << z << std::endl;
std::cout << "original nums: " << x << " " << y;
}
```

As for qt assuming Qlabel is the best method of output I am currently doing it by the method of:

```
int y = 10;
ui->labelOutput-> setText("hello i am " + QString::number(y));
```

But I just feel like there is probably a better alternative that I am not using. Converting the string to a number doesn't feel like the best method.

Or maybe this is the best method, in which case I will just need to get used to it.

EDIT:: Also, if I want to keep adding to the text label, like, in the case of cout, the console line was never overwritten but just added too. How would I achieve this? Like if 3 functions where to each add output, how would I ensure it is all displayed? i.e

```
line 1: output from function 1
line 2: output from function 2
line 3: output from function 3
```

rather than

```
line 1: output from function 1
```

then when function 2 runs

```
line 1: output from function 2
```

Comment: There is no better or worse, it all depends on the context, I recommend you check the description of each widget so that you understand what its use is.

Comment: `std`'s streams have this nice syntax because `operator<<` and `operator>>` are overloaded for the built-in types. Overload `operator+` for the built-in types and you won't have to cast a number to `QString` (no, don't do it, it will be really bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [QString::arg()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) formatting like this :

```
ui->labelOutput-> setText(QString("hello i am %1").arg(y));
```